# Why is my Python script setting all rows of my Postgres table as the same value?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Python3 script that checks the validity of URL's stored in a database and prints either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' in the terminal window depending on the result.

I'm trying to change it to upload the results into the same table but so currently it's just setting all rows in the column (url_valid type BOOL) as 'TRUE', unlike the printed results in the terminal which are correct.

I think it's because I don't include a "where" clause in my SQL queries, but that's because I'm not sure how to call the Python script's output from the SQL.

Other possibilities include my "cursor.execute(" or commit statements but I'm not sure.

Here's my code snippet:

```
dbconn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + user + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/' + database , echo=False)
dbconnraw = dbconn.raw_connection()
cur = dbconnraw.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT email_domain_url FROM contacts_unlisted_umatch')
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    try:
        response = requests.get(row[0])
        urlstat = response.status_code
        if urlstat<400:
            print('TRUE')
            cur.execute("UPDATE contacts_unlisted_umatch SET url_valid = 'TRUE'")
            dbconnraw.commit()
        else:
            print('FALSE')
            cur.execute("UPDATE contacts_unlisted_umatch SET url_valid = 'FALSE'")
            dbconnraw.commit()
    except Exception:
        print('FALSE')
        cur.execute("UPDATE contacts_unlisted_umatch SET url_valid = 'FALSE'")
        dbconnraw.commit()
        pass
```

What can I change to update the value of each individual row instead of setting them all as 'TRUE'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "WHERE" clause to your SQL statements. Without the "WHERE" clause, you are telling it to update every row inside of of the table.

For example, "UPDATE contacts_unlisted_umatch SET url_valid = 'TRUE' where email_domain_url = ..." and this will update only that "email_domain_url"'s url_valid value.

Comment: Yeah, I just added that to my question--but how do I do that for each url in the column?

Comment: So in your code, row[0] represents your databases "email_domain_url", so if you do: cur.execute(f"UPDATE contacts_unlisted_umatch SET url_valid = 'TRUE' WHERE email_domain_ur = '{row[0]}'"), you will update that rows respective "contacts_unlisted_umatch" match value. You would just repeat this through your other two SQL statements.

Comment: ahhh, okay. Yeah I was just trying %s but got a syntax error. I'm running it again with '{row[0]}' right now and will post the result shortly.

Comment: Make sure to start the string with with "f" to represent an f string in Python3

Comment: Perfect, that did it. Thanks!